# getche in C programming

Tags: c

I need help about using `getche`.
The problem is that I want to use an `int` and on that `int` I want to use `getche`,
but for example if I did:

```
int choice1 = 0;
choice1 = getche();
if(choice1 = 3)
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

but the problem is that even if I will choose 3 in the choice1 the program will think I meant some random note so it will print me hello no matter what I put.

Can someone help me in making my `getch` an `int`? (Not using `getche` is not an option I have to use it.)
thanks

Comment: `choice1 = 3` is assignment, not compare.

Comment: Code likely wants to compare to that character 3 and not the value 3.  `choice1 == '3'`

Comment: yeah, but what if i would like to do     int choice1, choice2 = 0; choice1 = getche(); choice2 = getche(); while(choice1 > 6 || choice2 > 6) and then print something then how do it do I. sry for the mess in the comment... new here

Comment: `getche` is non standard. Maybe you want [`getc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc). Read more about [C standard IO functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). Otherwise, you need to read the documentation of that `getche` (which does not exist on my Linux system C standard library), I never heard of it.

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask why you're limited to the non-standard (and unusual) `getche()`? Why is that the requirement of your project? You ought to use the standard C [`getc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) to get your character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int choice1 = 0;
    choice1 = getc(stdin);
    if (choice1 == '3') {     // note this line
        printf("hello");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reason your program is printing "hello" every time, is because you are not comparing your choice1 to the character "3". A single equals sign **=** is for *assignment*. You only use the single-equals to assign variables. To compare two values for equality, you use two equals signs **==**.

Your code would also be comparing the result of `getche()` to the actual value 3, and not what you want, which is the ASCII character '3'. Please make sure to specify the *ASCII character* **'3'** and not the value of 3 itself, which translates to a non-visible symbol.

Answer (score 0):

First: You made an assignment instead of condition, change the "choice = 3" to "choice == 3"

Second: check for the ASCII value of '0' and subtract it, so: '3' - '0' = 3 and so on

Comment: Thanks  i used the second one and did choice1 = getche()  - '0' and it went well thanks for the help

Comment: @StavoS just mark the answer as correct if that helped you ;)